# Has anybody built a plugin or API integration with Xero or Cin7?

Tags: plugins

Love hear thoughts on the complexity of this or if anyone has something off the shelf to offer. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if anyone **has already** built a plugin like that? Or are you asking **how** to build a plugin like that? Those are two very different questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. The complete list of known plugins can be found here:

> https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins